# Set hour to timeblock element using dayjs().hour()

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I am trying to set a Day.js hour object to an element. I am using `dayjs().hour(9)`, but it is returning too much information. I just want the hour block but when I `console.log` it comes back with day of the week date time with mins and seconds. In contrast when I `console.log(dayjs().hour())`, I just get the current hour. What else can I do?

Comment: _"which should log 9 in the console"_ - why? Per [the docs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/get-set/hour) `.hour(9)` sets the hour part to 9 _and returns a new dayjs object_. If you just want the value `9`, you already have it!

Comment: Previous comment as code snippet: `console.log(9)`.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it very well. I have variable that I am trying to assign dayjs().hour(9) value too. then I am using the isBefore or isAfter to compare that variable to the current dayjs().hour and then applying different CSS classes based on the results. But instead of hour 9 being compared to the current hour, dayjs is setting, the date, day and time with seconds and minutes. So my code is not working as I want.

Comment: What exactly is unclear? `dayjs().hour(9)` sets the hour value to 9 and returns the date object. In your question, you ask about `console.log`. If that's not your actual question, ask your actual question. You asked how to set an hour to an object and return the hour. You can use the comma operator: `dayjs().hour(9), 9`. It sets the hour and returns the number `9`.

Comment: I'm Console logging the values to show that its not working

Comment: When I console log the value of dayjs().hour(), I get the current hour logged or 9. When I set the value for hour9 = dayjs().hour(9) it returns M {$L: 'en', $d: Fri Apr 28 2023 09:53:40 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), $x: {…}, $y: 2023, $M: 3, …}
$D
: 
28
$H
: 
9
$L
: 
"en"
$M
: 
3
$W
: 
5
$d
: 
Fri Apr 28 2023 09:53:40 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) {}
$m
: 
53
$ms
: 
417
$s
: 
40
$x
: 
{}
$y
: 
2023
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object I can't compare those two values in with isAfter, isBefore. they are not equal.

Comment: Then, set the hour and get the hour. It's nonsense, but it seems to be what you want: `dayjs().hour(9).hour()`. See https://jsfiddle.net/8cgvjryt/

Answer (score 0):

`dayjs()` creates a new `dayjs` object with the current timestamp.

`dayjs().hour()` is a getter. It returns the hour value of the object.

`dayjs().hour(9)` is setter with fluent interface. It sets the hour value of the object and returns the whole `dayjs` object.

The fluent interface allows method chaining. You can set the value and get the value with `dayjs().hour(9).hour()`.

Example:

```js
console.log(dayjs().hour(9).hour());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

It's obvious that a code like `dayjs().hour(9).hour()` doesn't make much sense, because it creates a temporary object, sets the hour value, returns the same value and throws away the object. I assume that this is just a minimal code snippet to illustrate your case.

You can validate that the setter works with

```js
console.log(dayjs().hour(9).isBefore(dayjs().hour(10)));
console.log(dayjs().hour(9).isBefore(dayjs().hour(8)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```